# Split function gives 'Subscript out of range' error inside loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, split, vba

The code snippet below is attempting to look at the contents of a column of cells. Each cell is formatted: "X.XX_-_X.XX". For example: 5.66 - 13.44. The code is meant to take each cell, convert each of the strings to a double, compare them to some other numbers and then repeat for the next cell.

```
Sub Test()
Dim PC As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim MaxSpace, MinSpace As Double
Dim MinMax() As String

Set PC = Workbooks("RFQ_Worksheet").Worksheets("Press Choice")

For i = 7 To 52
    MinMax = Split(PC.Cells(i, 8), " - ", 2)
    MaxSpace = CDbl(MinMax(1))
    MinSpace = CDbl(MinMax(0))
    If MaxSpace > 10.3 Then
        'Do some stuff
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The line containing `MaxSpace = CDbl(MinMax(1))` gives a 'Subscript out of range' error. However, when I replace `PC.Cells(i, 8)` with `PC.Cells(7, 8)`, the code runs fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: it suggests that whatever value `i` is at the point of failure is a cell that is not in the format you are anticipating. When it errors, hit "Debug" and look at your "locals" pane (View>>Locals). Expand your `minmax` variable and see what is stored in both your `0` and `1` positions of that array. I suspect the entire string will be in `0` and `1` will be absent. Can't help further than that because it's most likely a data issue.

Comment: To keep from running errors you could do `If uBound(MinMax) >= 1 Then MaxSpace = CDbl(MinMax(1))` and just know that your `If MaxSpace > 10.3` is going to fail when it can't properly split, but you won't get an error.

Comment: There is one of your cells, in the range you are iterating over, that does not have " - " in it. Step through your code in debug mode so you can see which cell is causing the error.

Comment: @trincot: thank you for the hint, I initially thought it was just empty cells that caused troubles, but you are correct - it's the missing delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are hitting cells in your loop that don't have the delimiter.

Fix:

```
Sub Test()
Dim PC As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim MaxSpace As Double  'you didn't declare it properly
Dim MinSpace As Double
Dim MinMax() As String
Dim r As Range

Set PC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Press Choice")

For i = 7 To 52
    Set r = PC.Cells(i, 8)
    If InStr(r, " - ") <> 0 Then
        MinMax = Split(PC.Cells(i, 8), " - ", 2)
        MaxSpace = CDbl(MinMax(1))
        MinSpace = CDbl(MinMax(0))
        '... etc
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```